# Calculating sum with no direct join column

Tags: t-sql, join, sum

I have a table (ShipJourneys) where I need to calculate the Total Fuel Consumed which is a float value.  See the image below.

[image]

This value is obtained by summing all the individual consumers of fuel for a given vessel over the timeframe specified.  This data is contained in a second table.

[image]

Boxed in area in red shows there were 5 fuel consumers (specified by the FK_RmaDataSumsystemConfigID) and that 3 of the consumers had burned 0 units of fuel and 2 had each burned 29.

To calculate the totalFuelConsumed for that range of time frames, for a given vessel (stipulated by the FK_RmaID), the following query could be used

```
Select sum(FuelCalc) 
from FuelCalc 
where Timestamp >= '2019-07-24 00:00:00' 
and  Timestamp <= '2019-07-24 00:02:00' 
and FK_RmaID = 660
```

Using something like the query below does not work, resulting in bogus values

```
UPDATE  ShipJourneys 
SET TotalFuelConsumed = 
    (Select sum(FuelCalc) from FuelCalc as f 
    WHERE f.timestamp >= StartTimeUTC 
    and f.timestamp <= EndTimeUTC 
    and f.FK_RmaID = FK_RmaID)
```

Any suggestions on how I could join them

Comment: Update it to what? What part of this can you do? Eg update to a constant or a value based on the columns of its row. [ask] Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, includeing constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: I've edited the post.  The actual table data is more complex and resides on separate servers.  Leaving all of that complexity out I've done my best to further explain the problem

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS Anyway, if it is input, it should be initialization code simultaneously formatted as a table, part of a cut & paste & runnable [mre]. And a simpler yet still reprensentative example please.

Comment: Vessel? What vessel? An rmal? Please explain tables in terms of your application.  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.  When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. You seem to want sum/aggregate per rmal, why aren't you grouping by it? If you want a sum, you should have read re aggregates, so you should have read re grouping. This will be a faq when you clearly state in a sentence what wanted rows are.

Comment: It's not clear--do you want sum per range of dates, or sum per vessel, or what? And what is that sum as a sum over rows of what column per what column set & conditon of what table? Please also give desired output for given input.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
UPDATE myTable // Put the table correct name here
    SET TotalFuelConsumed = 
        Select sum(FuelUsed) from FuelTimeTbl as fuelTbl 
        WHERE fuelTbl.timestamp >= '2019-10-21 22:13:55.000' 
        and fuelTbl.imestamp <= '2019-11-27 17:10:58.000' 
        and fuelTbl.FK_RmaID = myTable.RmaID // Put the correct attribute name
```